# Scheme syntax: * in a list?

Tags: syntax, scheme

I'm new to Scheme.  Could someone please explain what `*` does in the following code?

```
(define pat2 '(or
           (list a g t a t a t g g a t a)
           (list g t a g g c c g t)
           (list c c c g a t a a a a a a g t g t c g t)
           (list c g a t c c c (junk 1) c g a t c t a)))
(define pat3 (list 'list pat2 '(junk 2)))
(define pat4 (list '* pat3))  ; I'm confused about the * here.
```

I'm aware that the contents of `pat4` would be something like

```
(*
  (list
  (or (list a g t a t a t g g a t a)
  (list g t a g g c c g t)
  (list c c c g a t a a a a a a g t g t c g t)
  (list c g a t c c c (junk 1) c g a t c t a))
  (junk 2)))
```

But I'm still confused as to what `*` is...it usually signifies multiplication but it couldn't possibly be for that here could it?

Thanks!

Comment: So literally just the symbol `*`?

Comment: Yes, just the symbol `*` ;p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply the symbol * (which is why it is quoted; quotation prevents the symbol from being evaluated).

If you execute your code, you'll see that pat4 is just pat3 with the * symbol in front:

```
> pat2
'(or (list a g t a t a t g g a t a) (list g t a g g c c g t) (list c c c g a t a a a a a a g t g t c g t) (list c g a t c c c (junk 1) c g a t c t a))
> pat3
'(list (or (list a g t a t a t g g a t a) (list g t a g g c c g t) (list c c c g a t a a a a a a g t g t c g t) (list c g a t c c c (junk 1) c g a t c t a)) (junk 2))
> pat4
'(* (list (or (list a g t a t a t g g a t a) (list g t a g g c c g t) (list c c c g a t a a a a a a g t g t c g t) (list c g a t c c c (junk 1) c g a t c t a)) (junk 2)))
```